# How can i manipulate data within a factor level by a subset of another factor in that level in a dataframe without loops

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, plyr

I have a data frame made up of absorption spectra from multiple sample runs (sample a, b, c, d), where Ydata is wavelength and Xdata is absorption. I am calculating a baseline corrected absorption by subtracting the average absorption over a quiet wavelength range away from peaks of interest.

simplified dataframe:

```
DF <- data.frame(
  group = rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d"),each=10),
  Ydata = rep(1:10, times = 4),
  Xdata = c(seq(1,10,1),seq(5,50,5),seq(20,11,-1),seq(0.3,3,0.3)),
  abscorr = NA
)
```

I need to correct each sample run by subtracting the mean of a subsetted wavelength range within the run. I've been doing it this way:

```
for (i in 1:length(levels(DF$group))){
  sub1 <- subset(DF, group == levels(DF$group)[i], select = c(group, Ydata, 
  Xdata));
  sub2 <- subset(sub1, Ydata > 4 & Ydata < 8, select = c(group, Ydata, 
  Xdata));
  sub1$abscorr <- sub1$Xdata - mean(sub2$Xdata);
  DF <- rbind(sub1, DF);
}
```

and then tidy up all the 'NA's

```
DF <- na.omit(DF)
```

The way done above is obviously clunky with use of loops. Is there a better way to go about this task for a large dataset? perhaps dplyr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `dplyr`:

```
DF %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    mutate(abscorr = Xdata - mean(Xdata[Ydata < 8 & Ydata > 4]))
```

Comment: thanks MT! works a treat. i couldn't get my head around how the dplyr package worked.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will do it.

```
fun <- function(x){
    x$Xdata - mean(x[which(x$Ydata > 4 & x$Ydata < 8), "Xdata"])
}
DF$abscorr <- do.call(c, lapply(split(DF, DF$group), fun))
```

Note that when I tested it, `all.equal` gave me a series of differences, namely the attributes of the two results are different. So I ran the following.

```
fun <- function(x){
    x$Xdata - mean(x[which(x$Ydata > 4 & x$Ydata < 8), "Xdata"])
}
DF2 <- DF
DF2$abscorr <- do.call(c, lapply(split(DF2, DF2$group), fun))

all.equal(DF[order(DF$group, DF$Ydata), ], DF2)
# [1] "Attributes: < Names: 1 string mismatch >"                                         
# [2] "Attributes: < Length mismatch: comparison on first 2 components >"                
# [3] "Attributes: < Component 2: names for target but not for current >"                
# [4] "Attributes: < Component 2: Attributes: < Modes: list, NULL > >"                   
# [5] "Attributes: < Component 2: Attributes: < Lengths: 1, 0 > >"                       
# [6] "Attributes: < Component 2: Attributes: < names for target but not for current > >"
# [7] "Attributes: < Component 2: Attributes: < current is not list-like > >"            
# [8] "Attributes: < Component 2: target is omit, current is numeric >"                  
# [9] "Component “abscorr”: Modes: numeric, logical"                                     
#[10] "Component “abscorr”: target is numeric, current is logical"
```

As you can see there is no difference in the calculated values of `abscorr`, only in the attributes. Among those, there are differences in the `na.omit` attribute or the `rownames`. I wouldn't worry if I were you, since the values of `abscorr` are equal.

**EDIT.**
Note that if I sort `DF` and then set the problem attributes to `NULL` both `all.equal` and the much more strict `identical` return `TRUE`.

```
DF1 <- DF[order(DF$group, DF$Ydata), ]  # Modify a copy, keep the original
row.names(DF1) <- NULL
attr(DF1, "na.action") <- NULL

all.equal(DF1, DF2)
#[1] TRUE
identical(DF1, DF2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks Rui - a nice base-R solution!